# Private messeging system Data base

Tags: php, message, private

when creating a data base for a website, Would I use the same data base that my users are using to log in to my website and just add tables to my existing data base? Or would I want to create a whole new data base with the tables for messaging?

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use my existing data base to make my private message data base or create a whole new data base just for messaging system.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to create an entirely new database, I would just stick with one database. No reason to have two. Just create the different table(s) for your messages.

Comment: You're very welcome! Not to say that's the end-all-be-all, but that's how I would handle it anyway.